# base href in environment - undefined after refresh

Tags: html, angularjs

in my angularjs app I set env.js like this one

```
(function (window) {
window.__env = window.__env || {};

// API url
window.__env.apiUrl = 'http://aaaaaaa.com/';

// Base url
window.__env.baseUrl = '/angular-app/';

// Whether or not to enable debug mode
// Setting this to false will disable console output
window.__env.enableDebug = true;
}(this));
```

In index html I call base href

```
<script>
        document.write('<base href="' + window.__env.baseUrl + '" />');
</script>
```

Everything on page work correct, I can refresh and everything is ok. But I have one page where I call many data from api. On First open, page work's ok, but only on that page, after refresh I lost all my js and css, I got many error

```
controller.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

this error for all js file, and also get

```
Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined
```

p.s.
I add env.js file to html

Answer (score 0):

OK, there is no answer so I improvised. I do not know is this ok, but work for me.
here is my solution. I extract location path name and set it to base href in index.html

```
 document.write('<base href="' + "/" + document.location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '/" />');
```